# Discord.js Error - Cannot Find Module

Tags: node.js, module, compiler-errors, discord.js

I am programming a bot for Discord using Discord.js. The bot has been working perfectly fine for this past month and the only updates I have made to the code these past few days was update Discord.js and Enmap. However, now when I try to run a command (in this example it's help) I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './commands/help.js'

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)

at Module.require (module.js:596:17)

at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

at module.exports (/app/events/message.js:162:17)

at emitOne (events.js:116:13)

at Client.emit (events.js:211:7)

at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/6c985a92-4a9b-4fa1- 
   bea8-7452f0bbbcd9/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/11.4.0/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)

at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/6c985a92-4a9b-4fa1- bea8-7452f0bbbcd9/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/11.4.0/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
```

This is how my command handler looks (in my main bot file):

```
client.commands = new Enmap();

fs.readdir("commands/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  files.forEach(file => {
    if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
    let command = `./commands/${file}`;
    let commandName = file.split(".")[0];
    client.commands.set(commandName, command);
    console.log(`Loaded ${commandName}`);
  });
});
```

And this is how the event message.js looks (a cooldown function is included here):

```
const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
console.log(args);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
console.log(command);
const cmd = require(client.commands.get(command));
if (!cmd || cmd === null) return;
else {
  var time = Date.now();
  if (client.cd.has(msg.author.id)) {
    var wait = client.cd.get(msg.author.id);
    if (time < wait) {
      msg.channel.send(new client.discord.RichEmbed().setColor(client.color).setDescription(`Please wait **${Math.ceil((wait - time)/1000)}** seconds before using another command!`)).then(msg => {msg.delete(2000).then(()=>{console.log("deleted")}).catch(error=> {console.error(error)})});
    }
    else {
      client.cd.set(msg.author.id, Date.now() + (client.sec * 1000));
      try {
        cmd.run(client, msg, args);
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    client.cd.set(msg.author.id, Date.now() + (client.sec * 1000));
    try {
      cmd.run(client, msg, args);
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
}
```

All of my command files also start with `exports.run = (client, msg, args) =>`

Is there any reason why Node.js/Discord.js would stop being able to read my command files? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I figured out what was causing an issue. All of my command files in my command folder started with `exports.run = (client, msg, args) =>` when it should have started with `module.exports = { name: 'command-name', run(client, msg, args) {` That way, Node.js would be able to recognize `cmd.run(client, msg, args)` as a function.

Answer (score -1):

```js
client.commands = new Discord.Client();

fs.readdir("/commands/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  let jsFile = files.filter(f => f.endsWith(".js");
  if(jsFile.length <= 0) return console.log("No JS Files!")
  files.forEach(file => {
    if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
    let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    console.log(`Loading ${file}`)

    client.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
  });
});
```

You're supposed to add the `/` before "commands"
and here are just some code suggestions that i've added.

Comment: The change from `new Enmap` to `new Discord.Client()` would completely break their code, as those two things aren't the same and are not interchangeable or compatible.